# Behavior of "?" is fishy when trying to rename all the files of current folder(thro' Batch Script) expecting that extension would be unchanged

Tags: windows, batch-file, wildcard, file-rename, batch-rename

I have been scripting in Windows(7 64Bit) Batch engine for sometime now.

What I find really disappointing is the `rename` command when trying to rename all files in a folder and using "?" to keep the file extension unaltered.

Please look at the below set of commands:

```
@echo off
set /p filename="Desired File Name: "
rename *.* "%filename%.???"
```

This is supposed to keep the file extension as it is but, on the contrary, if I pass the `filename` as "MONEY 2016" it unexpectedly renames the files to "MONEY 2016.201", why is that ?

Also, as debugging step, I printed the filename right after getting it inputted from the user, it prints as it is with spaces, so it doesn't seem like space issue at all..

How to make this work as expected with a one-liner as short as possible ?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that all extensions are three characters long, which is not generally the case. They could be any length at all. But let's assume for now that they are all 3 characters long in your particular folder. What are the original complete filenames (with extensions) in the folder (before renaming)?

Comment: A `For` loop is the way to go, `For %%A In (*.*)Do If Not Exist "%filename%%%~xA" Ren "%%A" "%filename%%%~xA" 2>Nul`.

Comment: @Klitos Kyriacou: The folder could contain files(with generally long names like those of Movies) of type video(with audio) and subtitles like MKV, AVI, MP4, SRT, SUB etc. But I want to write as generalised command/script as possible.

Comment: @Compo: That worked well..

Comment: It appears that `rename` considers `.201` segment as the destination extension and ignores the following  `.` and anything after. Any name containing a `.` generates the duplicate error as the same destination name and extension is repeating i.e. name `MONEY 2016` and extension `.201`. The name of `NewName` works, `New.Name` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my comment as an answer.

I'd suggest a `For` loop as a simple method of performing this task:

```bat
@Set /P "filename=Desired File Name: "
@For %%A In (*.*)Do @If Not Exist "%filename%%%~xA" Ren "%%A" "%filename%%%~xA" 2>Nul
```

*Please note that this method does not perform any verification of the user input. They could enter nothing, or they may enter a filename which is invalid. I'll leave it to you to implement a verification process, should you feel it necessary.*

Comment: While this works, it doesn't explain why the OP's attempt didn't. It worked for me when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the structure of original and new names. `*` certainly does *not* match `???` (this should be obvious). A `rename` command with the proper structure works well:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Tests> dir
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Tests

28/03/2019  10:12 p. m.    <DIR>          .
28/03/2019  10:12 p. m.    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 four.srt
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 one.mkv
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 three.avi
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 two.mp4
               4 archivos             28 bytes
               2 dirs  391,521,251,328 bytes libres

C:\Users\Antonio\Tests> rename *.* NewName.*

C:\Users\Antonio\Tests> dir
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Tests

28/03/2019  10:12 p. m.    <DIR>          .
28/03/2019  10:12 p. m.    <DIR>          ..
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 NewName.avi
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 NewName.mkv
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 NewName.mp4
28/03/2019  10:11 p. m.                 7 NewName.srt
               4 archivos             28 bytes
               2 dirs  391,521,251,328 bytes libres
```

Comment: But when I try `rename *.* %filename%.*` as per what you suggested(expecting it will work same with variable substitution as well), it gives error `The syntax of the command is incorrect`.

Comment: Well, if `%filename%` may contain spaces (you didn't mentioned this point, so I can only guess), then just enclose the new name between quotes as it appears in your original example: `rename *.* "%filename%.*"`. My only point is that `???` and `*` does _not_ match each other, so you must use _the same pattern_ at both original and new names...